# How to reset initial install directory of 2015 after using a custom install directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, visual-studio-2015

Problem: after installing Visual Studio 2015 Community to another partition (F:), Visual studio was not recognizing assemblies I installed.

How do I reset my installation to install to the default C:\ location so that the GAC assemblies are working properly?

Answer (score 0):

After much research and many uninstalls and frustration, I had to use the following tool to check which visual studio versions were installed in the registry.

In order to use the tool, I had to follow the instructions listed here by allowing Powershell to run scripts.

http://www.howtogeek.com/106273/how-to-allow-the-execution-of-powershell-scripts-on-windows-7/

I then had to run the following tool to check which versions of VS were installed.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/14/how-to-install-visual-studio-to-another-directory-when-a-pre-release-is-installed/

I was extremely satisfied when I was able to complete my installation in the default C:\ location.

Process:

Run Powershell under context of Admin (Listed in order):

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

get-msicomponentinfo '{777CBCAC-12AB-4A57-A753-4A7D23B484D3}' | get-msiproductinfo

get-msicomponentinfo '{777CBCAC-12AB-4A57-A753-4A7D23B484D3}' | get-msiproductinfo | uninstall-msiproduct -properties IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL

Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted

That allowed me to choose the default install location once again.

EDIT:

This helped me get my Visual studio up and running again but did not "solve" my problem.  My goal was to actually get Visual Studio 2015 Community up and running without any errors.  Turns out that after doing the below, it corrupted my installation and after multiple uninstalls/reinstalls, the only way to truly fix the problem was to just do a system refresh...very unfortunate.

I don't think I've ever had this problem when I uninstalled Visual Studio in the past.  This only occurred because I installed it to another partition (in my case).

I would never advise to do this unless absolutely necessary, but if you decide to install Visual Studio to another partition besides C:\, be prepared for a system refresh if all else fails as a last resort.